# Clear existing model in spring

Tags: spring-mvc, controller

I have a spring application in which I have a controller
**controller1**. Here I am creating a model object **model1** and setting view as **jsp1**. This is working fine and jsp1 is returning as view. On jsp1 I do certain task and again hit a controller **controller2** where model2 is created and jsp1 is set as view.
The problem is jsp2 is returned as view but it is retruned inside jsp1. Meaning UI part of jsp1 and jsp2 both is visible.
How can I clear the view of model1 so that only jsp2 is visible.

Something like this:

```
controller1{
ModelAndView model1 = new ModelAndView("jsp1");
return model1;}
controller2{
ModelAndView model2 = new ModelAndView("jsp2");
return model2;}
```

I am doing some task on jsp1 which calls controller2.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it. The problem was not with the controller instead it was with ajax call. After success, it was adding the html inside a div. Which instead of adding in the body was inserting in nested div.